# Loose binding of &

Tags: programming

This code returns `2`, as expected.

```
Quiet[Remove[f]];
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll];
f[code_, funct_: Function[x, x]] := funct[code];
f[
 a = 1;
 b = a + 1
 ]
```

This one returns `2` also, as expected.

```
Quiet[Remove[g]];
SetAttributes[g, HoldAll];
g[code_, funct_: ((##) &)] := funct[code];
g[
 a = 1;
 b = a + 1
 ]
```

Why this one returns `h[a=1;b=a+1]` ?

```
Quiet[Remove[h]];
SetAttributes[h, HoldAll];
h[code_, funct_: (##) &] := funct[code];
h[
 a = 1;
 b = a + 1
 ]
```

The reason,  perhaps, is related to the loose binding of `&`. In Documentation Center's `Function` entry is stated: "*`&` binds more loosely than `?`, so it usually needs parentheses in pattern tests*".

To verify the hypothesis, I have tried:

```
(* test f *)
Trace[
  f[
   a = 1;
   b = a + 1
   ]
  ] // Column
```

getting

```
f[a=1;b=a+1]
Function[x,x][a=1;b=a+1]
{a=1;b=a+1,{a=1,1},{{{a,1},1+1,2},b=2,2},2}
Function[x,x][2]
2
```

and

```
(* test g *)
Trace[
  g[
   a = 1;
   b = a + 1
   ]
  ] // Column
```

getting the same

```
g[a=1;b=a+1]
(##1&)[a=1;b=a+1]
{a=1;b=a+1,{a=1,1},{{{a,1},1+1,2},b=2,2},2}
(##1&)[2]
2
```

Lastly

```
(* test h *)    
Trace[
     h[
      a = 1;
      b = a + 1
      ]
     ]
```

getting

```
{}
```

Again,  `(* test f *)` and `(* test g *)` are easily understood; on the 
contrary `(* test h *)` is still demanding. Please, can you provide some    explanation ?

Comment: The pattern simply does not match for `h`, because, as you noted, the precedence of `&` is very low. In particular, `funct_: (##) & // FullForm` will give you `Function[Optional[Pattern[funct,Blank[]],SlotSequence[1]]]`, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like you said, `&` has very low precedence. You've written:

```
funct_: (##) &
```

`:` has a higher precedence than `&`, so this is actually equivalent to:

```
(funct_: (##) ) &
```

That is, an unnamed function with body `funct_: (##)`. Of course, your function call doesn't match this pattern, since supplying this argument is no longer optional. We can easily very this:

```
h[a = 1; b = a + 1, x &]

(* x[2] *)
```

Your pattern is actually a bit funny now, let's dissect it:

```
FullForm[funct_: (##) &]
(* Function[Optional[Pattern[funct, Blank[]], SlotSequence[1]]] *)
```

The pattern and default value are still used for pattern matching (although I don't think you can actually get at the default value since a function without a body isn't valid). That means, this should be equivalent to:

```
Function[Pattern[funct, Blank[]]]
```

That is, as long as you pass it a pure function, the pattern will match and `funct` will actually become the entire function *body* (without the pure function surrounding it). That's why passing it `x&` results in `x[2]`. Definitely not what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I fear I lack something to fully understand it. Is the following statement correct ? `Function[Optional[Pattern[funct,Blank[]],SlotSequence[1]]]` is a function (1) whose default (when no arguments are feeded in) return value is a pattern, named `func`, matching any expression  (2) that, instead, returns a pattern, unnamed, matching `arg` when `arg` is passed as argument ?

Comment: @mitochondrial Not really. The entire construction still acts as a pattern. Consider `{funct_: (##)}`. That's a pattern for a list with a single element called `funct`, which may be omitted in which case `funct` will default to `(##)`. In your case, you've got exactly the same situation, just that you expect your `funct` element to be inside a `Function` head instead of a `List` head. It's a really contrived situation that probably was never supposed to make a lot of sense. ;)

Comment: Yes, I fully agree. I run into this while experimenting with pattern matching, but this time I surely took an unproductive road ...